# pdf to word/office for linux

Tags: linux, pdf

I found many  converters (even free and downloadable), but not for linux. Can anybody please point me to a  good PDF2doc package that supports linux or even better specifically ubuntu, and free and downoadable?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/37548/pdf-to-word-conversion-software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Abiword. To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install abiword
```

To convert a document:

```
abiword --to=doc myfile.pdf
```

(answer taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37548/pdf-to-word-conversion-software))

Comment: thanks! I installed abiword; it does work -- to the extent (I have to figure out what to do with equations), and there are some warnings. But regular texts seem OK.